# gRPC send directly protobuf format

Tags: go, grpc

I got an service where I also want to use protobuf for the storage system. So instead of serialize the object from a protobuf wire format, I just want to read the database and send this result direct as response. I already researched within the generated and grpc code but it is, at the moment, still a mystery how it works. I get the response from the database as type of []byte. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto?

Comment: @dev.bmad Yes. Serialization of it shouldn't be the problem. But how to send it over the generated gRPC Server? On return streams I can only use send() with the generated struct message.

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://github.com/harshavardhana/grpc-gob-hello) that I've found on GitHub. It does a different job, but you can get the idea of what needs to be implemented (`grpc.Codec`, `grpc.ServiceDesc `, `grpc.MethodDesc`, etc).

Comment: @dev.bmax Thanks. Did a short look into the code. Looks good. I will try it at home. :)

Comment: Sorry, the problem is not clear: if you get `[]byte` from your Database, and you can define GRPC method which returns `[]byte` to the client, just connect GRPC server and Database client with each other.

Comment: @VitalyIsaev That's one way. I save the whole protobuf message response in the database. I want to return this message without serialization at all.